# Merging two Spring Application Context without closing the first application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-context

In our application start-up, we are creating one application context having its own bean configuration xml. Then depending up on certain logic, we would need to dynamically load/import the second bean configuration into the existing application context.

One option is to close the existing application context and creating a new application context by importing both the bean definition xml files. But closing the application context takes time ( i.e destroying beans/executors etc ) , is there a way to merge both the application context without closing the existing one.

Comment: You need to define what 'depending on certain logic' is to clarify this question. Spring Profiles are the generally accepted way of doing conditional beans.

Comment: Do you need the context to execute the logic? Why not execute that before? Another solution would be to use the context you already have as a parent for the other context.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I was able to fix it by using the parent as the other context.   ApplicationContext masterContext = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(master,true,aaspireBaseContext);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using multiple application contexts you can achieve a hierarchy, which might be helpful here. You then first create the first instance, determine what to load next in a new instance with the first instance as a parent.

Something like this

```java
ApplicationContext parent= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("your-context.xml");
String nextXml = logicToDetermineXml();
ApplicationContext toUse = new (new String[] {nextXml}, parent);
```

Now you can use the one called `toUse` for the remainder of your application. Without having to recreate the whole context.